# PyQGIS line break in a case/when expression

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, qgis-expression

Is it possible to create a line break in this expression? I would like to display the expression more clearly in a PyQGIS-script. I use the processing tool in a Python-Script which runs in QGIS.

```
processing.run("qgis:selectbyexpression", {'INPUT':'/home/klaus-linux/ins-Netz/B880_Brenner/GIS/PA2/konflikte/kon_bio_var2_1_70_f_akt.shp','EXPRESSION':'CASE\n  --kein Eingriff \n  WHEN   "tpl"like \'%kein%Eingrif%\' then 0\n  --BNT mit 0 WP\n  WHEN   "bpkte" = 0 then 0\n  ----Punkt. 5 auf Seite 6: letzter Absatz: BNT, die per Definition nie betroffen sind\n  WHEN  "bnt" in( \'V11\' , \'V12\', \'V32\' ,\'P5\' ) THEN 0\n  --Punkt 1 auf Seite 6: Dauerhafte Überbauung von BNT mit WP >0\n  WHEN   "bpkte" > 0 and  "tpl" in( \'Anlage (Fahrbahn, Bankett)\' , \'Anlage (sonstige Versiegelung)\' ) THEN 1 \n  --Punkt. 2a auf Seite 6: Begrünbare Böschungen und WP >3 und <11\n  WHEN   "bpkte" > 3 and "bpkte" <11 and "tpl" in( \'Anlage (begrünbare Fläche)\',\'Anlage (begrünbare Böschung)\' ,\'Anlage (begrünbare Nebenflächen)\',\'Anlage (begrünbare Flächen unter Brücken)\'  ) THEN 0.7 \n  --Punkt. 2b auf Seite 6: Begrünbare Böschungen und WP >10\n  WHEN   "bpkte" > 10 and  "tpl" in( \'Anlage (begrünbare Fläche)\',\'Anlage (begrünbare Böschung)\' ,\'Anlage (begrünbare Nebenflächen)\',\'Anlage (begrünbare Flächen unter Brücken)\'  ) THEN 1 \n  --Punkt. 3 auf Seite 6: Betriebesbedingte Beeintr. und WP > 3\n  WHEN   "bpkte" > 3 and  "tpl" in( \'Betrieb (Verkehrsneubelastung)\'  ) THEN 0.4 \n  --Punkt. 3 auf Seite 6: Betriebesbedingte Beeintr. und WP > 3\n  WHEN   "bpkte" > 3 and  "tpl" in( \'Bau (BE-Fläche)\',\'Bau (sonstiges)\' ,\'Bau (sonstige)\' ) THEN 0.4\n  --Punkt. 5 auf Seite 6: letzter Absatz\n  WHEN   "bpkte" < 4 and  "tpl"like \'Bau%\' THEN 0\n  WHEN   "bpkte" < 4 and  "tpl"like \'Anlage (begrünb%\' THEN 0\n  --Regelung zum Rückschnitt bei B880/BNT Gruppe B\n  WHEN   "tpl"  like \'Betriebs%ückschnit%\'and "bnt" like \'B%\' and "bpkte" > 10 then 1\n  WHEN   "tpl"  like \'Betriebs%ückschnit%\'and "bnt" like \'B%\' and "bpkte" > 3 and "bpkte" <11  then 0.7\n  WHEN   "tpl"  like \'Betriebs%ückschnit%\'and "bnt" like \'B%\' and "bpkte" < 4  then 0\n  --Regelung zum Rückschnitt bei B880/BNT Gruppe L\n  WHEN   "tpl"  like \'Betriebs%ückschnit%\'and "bnt" like \'L%\' and "bpkte" > 10 then 1\n  WHEN   "tpl"  like \'Betriebs%ückschnit%\'and "bnt" like \'L%\' and "bpkte" > 3 and "bpkte" <11  then 0.7\n  WHEN   "tpl"  like \'Betriebs%ückschnit%\'and "bnt" like \'L%\' and "bpkte" < 4  then 0\n  --Regelung zum Rückschnitt bei B880/BNT Gruppe N\n  WHEN   "tpl"  like \'Betriebs%ückschnit%\'and "bnt" like \'N%\' and "bpkte" > 10 then 1\n  WHEN   "tpl"  like \'Betriebs%ückschnit%\'and "bnt" like \'N%\' and "bpkte" > 3 and "bpkte" <11  then 0.7\n  WHEN   "tpl"  like \'Betriebs%ückschnit%\'and "bnt" like \'N%\' and "bpkte" < 4  then 0\n  --Regelung zum Rückschnitt bei B880/BNT Gruppe W\n  WHEN   "tpl"  like \'Betriebs%ückschnit%\'and "bnt" like \'w%\' and "bpkte" > 10 then 1\n  WHEN   "tpl"  like \'Betriebs%ückschnit%\'and "bnt" like \'w%\' and "bpkte" > 3 and "bpkte" <11  then 0.7\n  WHEN   "tpl"  like \'Betriebs%ückschnit%\'and "bnt" like \'w%\' and "bpkte" < 4  then 0\n  --Regelung zum Rückschnitt bei B880/BNT zu allen anderen Gruppen außer B, L, N und W\n  WHEN   "tpl"  like \'Betriebsbedingter Rückschnitt\'and "BYKV_E1K" in(\'A\',\'F\',\'G\',\'H\',\'K\',\'M\',\'0\',\'P\',\'Q\',\'R\',\'S\',\'V\',\'X\',\'Z\') then 0\n  Else -1000\nEND','METHOD':0})
```

Comment: Python has three different ways to quote strings, and once inside a paren or brace, you don't need to keep it all in one line anyway. But there isn't anything GIS-centric about this; it's just plain vanilla Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not a GIS question, pure Python formatting.
Code not tested, the `CASE WHEN` logic can be improved.

```py
shp_path = "/home/klaus-linux/ins-Netz/B880_Brenner/GIS/PA2/konflikte"
expression = """
CASE
  --kein Eingriff
  WHEN "tpl" LIKE '%kein%Eingrif%' THEN 0
  --BNT mit 0 WP
  WHEN "bpkte" = 0 THEN 0
  --Punkt. 5 auf Seite 6: letzter Absatz: BNT, die per Definition nie betroffen sind
  WHEN "bnt" IN ('V11', 'V12', 'V32', 'P5') THEN 0
  --Punkt 1 auf Seite 6: Dauerhafte Überbauung von BNT mit WP >0
  WHEN "bpkte" > 0 AND "tpl" IN ('Anlage (Fahrbahn, Bankett)', 'Anlage (sonstige Versiegelung)') THEN 1
  --Punkt. 2a auf Seite 6: Begrünbare Böschungen und WP >3 und <11
  WHEN "bpkte" > 3 AND "bpkte" < 11 AND "tpl" IN ('Anlage (begrünbare Fläche)', 'Anlage (begrünbare Böschung)', 'Anlage (begrünbare Nebenflächen)', 'Anlage (begrünbare Flächen unter Brücken)') THEN 0.7
  --Punkt. 2b auf Seite 6: Begrünbare Böschungen und WP >10
  WHEN "bpkte" > 10 AND "tpl" IN ('Anlage (begrünbare Fläche)', 'Anlage (begrünbare Böschung)', 'Anlage (begrünbare Nebenflächen)', 'Anlage (begrünbare Flächen unter Brücken)') THEN 1
  --Punkt. 3 auf Seite 6: Betriebesbedingte Beeintr. und WP > 3
  WHEN "bpkte" > 3 AND "tpl" IN ('Betrieb (Verkehrsneubelastung)') THEN 0.4
  --Punkt. 3 auf Seite 6: Betriebesbedingte Beeintr. und WP > 3
  WHEN "bpkte" > 3 AND "tpl" IN ('Bau (BE-Fläche)', 'Bau (sonstiges)', 'Bau (sonstige)') THEN 0.4
  --Punkt. 5 auf Seite 6: letzter Absatz
  WHEN "bpkte" < 4 AND "tpl" LIKE 'Bau%' THEN 0
  WHEN "bpkte" < 4 AND "tpl" LIKE 'Anlage (begrünb%' THEN 0
  --Regelung zum Rückschnitt bei B880/BNT Gruppe B
  WHEN "tpl" LIKE 'Betriebs%ückschnit%' AND "bnt" LIKE 'B%' AND "bpkte" > 10 THEN 1
  WHEN "tpl" LIKE 'Betriebs%ückschnit%' AND "bnt" LIKE 'B%' AND "bpkte" > 3 AND "bpkte" < 11 THEN 0.7
  WHEN "tpl" LIKE 'Betriebs%ückschnit%' AND "bnt" LIKE 'B%' AND "bpkte" < 4 THEN 0
  --Regelung zum Rückschnitt bei B880/BNT Gruppe L
  WHEN "tpl" LIKE 'Betriebs%ückschnit%' AND "bnt" LIKE 'L%' AND "bpkte" > 10 THEN 1
  WHEN "tpl" LIKE 'Betriebs%ückschnit%' AND "bnt" LIKE 'L%' AND "bpkte" > 3 AND "bpkte" < 11 THEN 0.7
  WHEN "tpl" LIKE 'Betriebs%ückschnit%' AND "bnt" LIKE 'L%' AND "bpkte" < 4 THEN 0
  --Regelung zum Rückschnitt bei B880/BNT Gruppe N
  WHEN "tpl" LIKE 'Betriebs%ückschnit%' AND "bnt" LIKE 'N%' AND "bpkte" > 10 THEN 1
  WHEN "tpl" LIKE 'Betriebs%ückschnit%' AND "bnt" LIKE 'N%' AND "bpkte" > 3 AND "bpkte" < 11 THEN 0.7
  WHEN "tpl" LIKE 'Betriebs%ückschnit%' AND "bnt" LIKE 'N%' AND "bpkte" < 4 THEN 0
  --Regelung zum Rückschnitt bei B880/BNT Gruppe W
  WHEN "tpl" LIKE 'Betriebs%ückschnit%' AND "bnt" LIKE 'w%' AND "bpkte" > 10 THEN 1
  WHEN "tpl" LIKE 'Betriebs%ückschnit%' AND "bnt" LIKE 'w%' AND "bpkte" > 3 AND "bpkte" < 11 THEN 0.7
  WHEN "tpl" LIKE 'Betriebs%ückschnit%' AND "bnt" LIKE 'w%' AND "bpkte" < 4 THEN 0
  --Regelung zum Rückschnitt bei B880/BNT zu allen anderen Gruppen außer B, L, N und W
  WHEN "tpl" LIKE 'Betriebsbedingter Rückschnitt' AND "BYKV_E1K" IN ('A','F','G','H','K','M','0','P','Q','R','S','V','X','Z') THEN 0
  ELSE -1000
END
"""
params = {
    "INPUT": f"{shp_path}/kon_bio_var2_1_70_f_akt.shp",
    "EXPRESSION": expression,
    "METHOD": 0,
}
processing.run("qgis:selectbyexpression", params)
```

Comment: thx for your super service